# Converting Json code to C# (numbers as keys)

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, entity

I get some json code from web services in Windows Phone 8. I generate my entities class thanks to the site json2csharp (http://json2csharp.com/). But there is a web service that has strange json code, like this. There is numbering as keys (0,1,2):

```
{
  "service": "MainMapService",
  "func": "getPlacesByAxes",
  "result": {
    "0": {
      "id": "13478",
      "date": "0",
      "id_cat": "1",
      "id_cat_sub": "0",
      "id_user": "0",
     },
    "2": {
      "id": "23272",
      "date": "0",
      "id_cat": "1",
      "id_cat_sub": "0",
      "id_user": "667"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "21473",
      "date": "0",
      "id_cat": "1",
      "id_cat_sub": "0",
      "id_user": "0"
     }
   },
  "args": [
    "1",
    "50.8",
    "4.5",
    "1"
  ]
}
```

And json2csharp generates classes like this... Each class for a number:

```
public class __invalid_type__0
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id_cat { get; set; }
    public string id_cat_sub { get; set; }
    public string id_user { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id_cat { get; set; }
    public string id_cat_sub { get; set; }
    public string id_user { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string id_cat { get; set; }
    public string id_cat_sub { get; set; }
    public string id_user { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public __invalid_type__0 __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__2 __invalid_name__2 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__1 __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string func { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public List<string> args { get; set; }
}
```

So, the problem comes from the numbering keys and there may be several numbers. Do you know how can I resolve this? I can't change the Json code...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is far from elegant, but give it a try.

So, what is my idea:

I have created two classes

`RootObject` helper

> ```
> public class YourJsonClass
> {
>   public string service { get; set; }
>   public string func { get; set; }
>   public dynamic result { get; set; }
>   public string[] args { get; set; }
> }
> ```

`result` helper

```
public class Item
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string date { get; set; }
            public string id_cat { get; set; }
            public string id_cat_sub { get; set; }
            public string id_user { get; set; }
        }
```

I'm using `newtonsoft json`

```
 var m_res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJsonClass>(YourJsonResponce);        
            foreach (dynamic numb in m_res.result)
            {

                string m_name = numb.Name; // it will be "1", "0" or whatever
                string h = numb.Value.ToString();
                var m_value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(h);

            }
```

... indeed there are better ways, but i hope this will help (:

Comment: I simplified the code by remplacing dynamic type by a dictionnary ( Dictionary<int, Item> )
And thus, we can manipulate the dictionnary to avoid the loop that deserialize again


var ra = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJsonClass>(e.Result);

List<Item> allItems = ra.result.Values.ToList();

List<int> allKeys = ra.result.Keys.ToList();

Comment: it's a nice feeling when you work hard and something good came out